# Parse contents of .txt file to HTML file using Bash

Tags: bash

I have a task to parse contents of text file into the part of HTML. For example I have a file `CONTENTS.txt` which the contents have format like this:

```
<div class="page-header">
   <h3>TITLE1</h3> 
</div>

<p>CONTENT1 BLABLABLALBA</p>
<p>CONTENT1 BLALALBALBALA</p>
<br/>

<div class="page-header">
     <h3>TITLE2</h3> 
</div>

<p>CONTENT2 BLABLABLALBA</p>
<p>CONTENT2 BLALALBALBALA</p>
<p>CONTENT2 BLALALBALBALA</p>
<br/>

<div class="page-header">
     <h3>TITLE3</h3> 
</div>

<p>CONTENT3 BLABLABLALBA</p>
```

And what i want is to insert them to the something part of the HTML in `HOME.html` like in

```
<div class="span6">

.................

</div>
```

How to do that in bash script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility, using `sed`:

In your `HOME.html` file, put a placeholder where you want `CONTENTS.txt` to be inserted, e.g.,

```
<div class="span6">
@@CONTENTS.txt@@
</div>
```

Then use `sed` as:

```
sed -e '/@@CONTENTS.txt@@/{rCONTENTS.txt' -e ';d}' HOME.html
```

---

Regarding your comment:

You should have a template file, say `HOME-template.html` that contains your structure and the placeholders, say:

```
<div class="span6">
@@CONTENTS.txt@@
</div>
```

and you should generate your `HOME.html` file like so:

```
sed -e '/@@CONTENTS.txt@@/{rCONTENTS.txt' -e ';d}' HOME-template.html > HOME.html
```

So that each time you change your `CONTENTS.txt` file, you run this command, and the `HOME.html` will reflect the changes.

Comment: Thanks for the response. By the way, is the script still valid when the the tag <div class="span6"> </div> had already filled?

Comment: @hadyan I don't really understand what you mean there. The `sed` command outputs (to std out) the content of `HOME.html` with the line containing the placeholder `@@CONTENTS.txt@@` replaced by the content of the file `CONTENTS.txt`. If there are no placeholders, the file is just sent to stdout...

Comment: i mean if the placeholder already replaced with the content of the file `CONTENTS.txt`, did the script still running well if i update the contents in `CONTENTS.txt`?

Comment: @hadyan I've added some stuff that should address your question.

Comment: wow it works dude, thanks. By the way i have another question, can i run the script from the file, for example `test.sh` tha contain the original script? I already try to run that but nothing happened. If i run the script directly from terminal it works. Is there something wrong?

Comment: @hadyan There shouldn't be any problem in running from a script. Just make sure that the file `CONTENTS.txt` is in the directory from where you run the script, or otherwise put the full path of the file in the `sed` command: `sed -e '/@@CONTENTS.txt@@/{r/path/to/file/CONTENTS.txt' -e ';d}' HOME-template.html > HOME.html`

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if the question makes full sense

https://github.com/vahidhedayati/replace_content take a look here  - using replace.sh you could run

```
replace.sh "TAG" "new content" file.txt
```

This will then replace the tags in the text file to the relevant html content you require - you could then copy the file as name.html or whatever.

Again I am still unsure if I have understood your question properly:

Assuming you have this file called file1.txt

```
<div class="page-header">
   <h3>TEMPLATE_TITLE</h3> 
</div>

<p>CONTENT1</p>
<p>CONTENT1_TAG1</p>
<br/>
```

you could run 
replace.sh "TEMPLATE_TITLE" "New Title" file1.txt
replace.sh "CONTENT1" "New Content" file1.txt
replace.sh "CONTENT1_TAG1" "New tag" file1.txt

which will replace per call the tags you wish to replace - you could add an entire segment to it so replace tag with segment of html.... -

Get further creative get it to write the output to a new file itself etc by updating replace.sh .....

Comment: I don't understand about the parameters listed above. Could you please give the example about running replace.sh script from my case?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
line_number=$(sed -n '/<div class="span6">/=' home.html)
head -n $line_number home.html > output.html
cat contents.txt >> output.html
tail -n +$(($line_number+1)) home.html >> output.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a here document with the `cat` command.

```
cat <<EOF > HOME.html
<div class="span6">
$(<CONTENTS.txt)
</div>
EOF
```